# Outlook reminder get AppointmentItem

Tags: c#, outlook

Is there a way to know if a Outlook.reminder is owned by a AppointmentItem ?
I've got a eventHandler which is fired when a reminder is fired. In this case i would like to know which Outlook item owns the reminder and if it is an AppointmentItem if it fit other rules to dismiss the reminder.

```
 storage._Explorers = this.Application.Explorers;
 storage._Explorers.Application.Reminders.ReminderFire += new Outlook.ReminderCollectionEvents_ReminderFireEventHandler(Application_ReminderFire);
```

...

```
static void Application_ReminderFire(Outlook.Reminder reminder) {
        object item = reminder.Parent;
        if (item is Outlook.AppointmentItem) {
            AppointmentItem appointment = (item as AppointmentItem);
            MAPIFolder folder = appointment.Parent;

            StringCollection collection = Properties.Settings.Default.CALENDARS_SETTINGS;

            foreach (string chaine in collection) {
                string[] values = chaine.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                if (folder.Name == values[0]) {
                    Boolean reminderChecked = Boolean.Parse(values[1]);
                    if (!reminderChecked) {
                        MessageBox.Show(reminder.Caption, "DISMISS", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are you using for `storage.` ?  A custom class?

Comment: Yes ! I use à custom class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Reminder.Item` property - it will return the corresponding `AppointmentItem`, `TaskItem`, `MailItem`, etc. You will need to check the actual type and/or cast it to the appropriate object.

Comment: I didn't saw the Item in the object ! Thank you all works very well now :)